# How can i get the Laplace Transfer function for control process for quadcopter?

Tags: quadcopter, control

I'm a beginner for quadcopter construction with PID controller and PIC 16F877 microcontroller. Now, I'm troubling with how do make the control process with mathematical model for my quadcopter :( and how to draw flow chart for this?

Comment: There are many potential answers to your question, depending on what you really need to know.  For example, is your background in controls, so you understand Laplace transforms and PID loops, but you are just having trouble modeling the 'copter?  Or are you a complete newcomer to both controls and UAVs?  Do you understand programming?  Do you understand engineering analysis and PDEs?  And, finally, what have you tried to do that didn't lead to proper definition of a control model for your system?

Comment: You have to linearize your model around a certain point in order to get a transfer function from it.